# Multiple "Skipping acquire of configured file"

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I'm trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS, but whenever I click upgrade, it closes the Software Updater tab and does nothing.  When I try to update from the terminal, it says not all packages are updated. So I go to update from the terminal and get the following.

[image]

Comment: Somewhere, there is an "1386" that should be "i386". Please do `grep -R 1386 /etc/apt/*` and see what it turns up.

Comment: Nothing happens. No results.

Comment: I believe I have fixed it with some help from a few friends. By running `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386` to remove the architecture entirely. Afterwards, I ran `sudo apt update` and no more "Skipping acquire..." was shown.